# How many types of pyroelectric sensor exist?

Tags: pir

I'm developing a PIR sensor, I'm new in this (PIR sensors) and saw that there are sensors that have two elements while some have four elements. Are there more types? What's the difference? Is there something else that I must to take in account?

I tried to find some info but get nothing, all the sites talk about a finished product not the sensor itself.

Answer (score 1):

A PIR sensor works by detecting the variation in the difference between what is received by two elements.

If you have only two elements, the sensor will (in theory) only be able to detect if there is a variation along one axis. If you have four elements, it can detect in two different directions.

This is greatly simplified because the Fresnel lens in front of the sensor (which focuses IR from the direction of each of the facets of the lens onto the sensor) will often result in complex detection patterns which are not just one direction or its orthogonal, but it does have an influence on sensitivity to movement in each direction.

Other possible differences include:

- Sensitivity
- Power consumption
- Immunity to other signals, especially sunlight
- The pattern of detection, in number of detection zones, field of view, orientation (dictated by the lens rather than the sensor itself)
- Cost
- Size

And probably a few others which don’t come to mind.

The electronics after the sensor will also include logic for delay, dwell time, etc. Some sensors will for instance have a high output only when movement is actually detected, others will keep the output high a few seconds or minutes after last movement.

Then if you get out of passive sensors (i.e. IR, not PIR) you get thermal sensors which give a temperature, or possibly an array of temperatures (for a few pixels to a few hundred, after which isn’t becomes a thermal camera). But the cost and power draw are quite different for all those.

Remember that PIR sensors only detect variations in the difference of the signal along their axis. They do not detect actual presence. Someone not moving or moving very little (sleeping, sitting still, even someone typing on a computer) will be invisible to a PIR sensor. A better sensitivity helps here, to a point.

Comment: So, if I use a 2 elements sensor I must to use a different Fresnel than if I use a 4 elements sensor? Currently I'm using a D205-B but probably on production they will use a D203 or something similar.